# Get combination images for product in order detail in Prestashop 1.6.0.14

Tags: php, html, prestashop, product, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to get my order detail to show image for the combination of the product from order instead of the cover image.

I am a little bit lost for what exactly to change in the below code. Step by step explaination will be appreciated.

I have this in my `class/order/Order.php` file:

```html
public function getProductsDetail()
{
return Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS('
SELECT *
FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail` od
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product p ON ( p.id_product = od.product_id)
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang pl ON (pl.id_product = p.id_product)
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'image i ON (i.id_product = p.id_product AND i.cover = 1)
WHERE od.`id_order` = '.(int)($this->id));
}
```

And this in `/controller/front/OrderDetailController.php`:

```html
$id_lang_default= Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
foreach($products as $key => $value) {
$objet_produit= new Product($value['product_id']);

$products[$key]['link_rewrite']= $objet_produit->link_rewrite[$id_lang_default];
$products[$key]['cover']= Product::getCover($value['product_id']);
}
```

And this snippet is in `order-detail.tpl`:

```html
<img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.cover.id_image, 'small_default')}" title="{$product.product_name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" alt="{$product.product_name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" />
```